# Imagemagick combine 2 generated PDFs into 1 multi-page file

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, multipage

I'm not finding in the documentation where to take 2 PDFs and combine them into 1 file where image1.pdf will be page 1 and image2.pdf will be page2.

Is this even possible?

I see documentation where you can pull images and do a lot of processing FROM a multi-page PDF but not on how to combine them.

**This seems to have worked but with major loss of quality.  I'm sure there is a way to combine without touching PDF quality, density, degradation, etc.

`exec("convert image1.pdf image2.pdf combined.pdf");`

Comment: You can use [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) to do this much simpler - are you limited to imagemagick?

Comment: Unfortunately the entire website is programmed in Imagemagick and on GoDaddy servers so i'm limited yes.  It needs to be where a monkey can do it which is why I have it so a user manipulates 2 images and it combines them automatically.  I hoped Imagemagick could do it somehow.

Comment: If the imagemagick on your server is able to manipulate the pdfs at all it must be using the ghostscript delegate under the hood.  Try [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/54041/how-to-merge-pdfs-using-imagemagick-resolution-problem) first using ghostscript directly for best results.

Comment: I believe you are right.  I tried a very simple line of code which i'll paste above in my question but the resolution is awful.  I'll keep looking for how to make it go image1.PDF, image2.PDF, -> combined.PDF without loss of quality.  i'd like to mark your answer as correct but it's not in an answer box.  i'll give you a upvote though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
convert page1 page2 output.pdf
```

You posted just before me :(

I think you will have to add a density.

Comment: That works but it's so blocky it must be somehow changing the quality, resolution, density or something.  Searching for how to combine PDFs without loss of quality.

Comment: Imagemagick uses raster and I suppose it converts from pdf to raster and back to pdf.

Comment: density worked.  i kept it at 300 but it did make a 9mb and 7mb file become 35mb... weird!

Comment: The reason for the bloat is likely because ImageMagick is rendering the pdf as a raster image.  Using ghostscript directly avoids this problem...

Answer (score 22):

If the imagemagick on your server is able to manipulate the pdfs at all it must be using the ghostscript delegate under the hood. Try the answer [used here](https://superuser.com/questions/54041/how-to-merge-pdfs-using-imagemagick-resolution-problem) first using ghostscript directly for best results.

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -q -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=temp.pdf pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf
```

Comment: Worked with me (old version for Debian, Dec 2008), and preserved resolution and color (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Unlike imagemagick, gs doesn't touch the data. I combined PDFs with images, extracted with `pdfimages` and tested with `md5sum`. Also IDKW imm add some white pages in between.